# I am looking to recreate a mathematical equation from HTML

Tags: html, reverse-engineering, equation

I have the following mathematical equation (posted below) that I lost the source file and the best thing I have is the HTML version which has somehow scrambled the actual equation and has a bunch of gibberish values in it. My HTML prowess is extremely rudimentary and it would mean the world to me if somebody could help me to recreate the equation. Thanks in advance.

```
IT = SH*((1-KD)*RD+0.5*(1+cosÎ²)*K+0.5*(1-cosÎ²)*Ï)â€¦â€¦(1) TC= (TA + (TNOCT -TS)*(IO/IL))â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦...â€¦(2) Dm=Dp*Dec*Dim*DNOCTâ€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦.â€¦â€¦
.(3)
Dec= DC* DMIS* DTâ€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦(4) DC= DO + (1-Î±*TC- TA))
â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦.(5) Area (m2)= Load / (D*ID)â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦(6) Q (Kwh) = (C + NSR)*Load / (DOD* DB)â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦.(7)
DOD= 1-
SOCâ€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦.(8) IT-ID= M*Sâ€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦.(9) XPV= (X0*((1+go)/(k-go))*(1- ((1+go)/(1+ko))N)â€¦â€¦â€¦..â€¦(10)
RPV= b*Q*(1-s)*  ^ (N*i/(NR+1))â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦â€¦(11
)
```

Comment: HTML can't do equations. Plus your question sounds like a load of BS.

Comment: as @j08691 said we don't do stuff for you, we help you, so unless you provide us with some code, we cant help you

Comment: Look into https://www.mathjax.org/.

Answer (score 2):

This *looks* like cp-1252. Re-encoding this from `cp-1252` to `utf-8` and removing the dots gives this. No idea if it's meaningful:

> IT = SH*((1-KD)RD+0.5(1+cosβ)K+0.5(1-cosβ))(1)
>   TC= (TA + (TNOCT -TS)(IO/IL)) (2)
>   Dm=DpDecDimDNOCT (3)
>   Dec= DC DMIS* DT (4)
>   DC= DO + (1-αTC- TA)) (5)
>   Area (m2)= Load / (DID) (6)
>   Q (Kwh) = (C + NSR)Load / (DOD DB) (7)
>   DOD= 1- SOC (8)
>   IT-ID= MS (9)
>   XPV= (X0((1+go)/(k-go))(1- ((1+go)/(1+ko))N) (10)
>   RPV= bQ*(1-s)* ^ (N*i/(NR+1))(11)